# Toolkit php / Salesforce : Change lang

Tags: php, salesforce, soql

I would like to know if it is possible with the php toolkit for salesforce to modify the language used during the API? or f i must have an account per language used.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need separate integration accounts.

But you should write up your use case a bit more. You're supposed to insert data in org's master language anyway. Language matters only if you write queries with `SELECT TOLABEL(Some_picklist__c) FROM Account`, correct? And perhaps if you have some formula fields that would reference some custom labels...

You should be able to issue from PHP an `update` operation to your own user that changes your language (the field name is `LanguageLocaleKey` and valid values - well, you can take it from the picklist on User or this should work too: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=5